# Limit of a integral

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, analysis

For $f:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ continuous, let $a >0.$

\begin{eqnarray*}
L=\lim_{\varepsilon \rightarrow 0}\int_{\varepsilon a}^{\varepsilon b} \frac{f(x)}{x} dx
\end{eqnarray*}

Show that $L=f(0)\ln(\frac{b}{a})$.The first I thought was in mean value theorem for integrals. but  I don't know how can start, if can give me some hint to start. I will be gratefull.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $0<a<b$. By direct calculation, for any $t>0$, $\int_{ta}^{tb}\frac{f(0)}{x}dx=f(0)\ln(b/a).$

Let $\varepsilon>0$ be given. We choose $\delta\in(0,1)$ such that $|f(x)-f(0)|<\varepsilon\cdot\frac{1}{\ln(b/a)}$
whenever $x\in[0,\delta]$. (Note that $\ln(b/a)>0$.) Let
$t_{0}=\frac{\delta}{b}.$ Let $t\in(0,t_{0})$ be arbitrary.
Note that $x\in[ta,tb]\Rightarrow x\in[0,\delta]$, so we have
estimation
\begin{eqnarray*}
 &  & \left|\int_{ta}^{tb}\frac{f(x)}{x}dx-f(0)\ln(b/a)\right|\\
 & = & \left|\int_{ta}^{tb}\frac{f(x)}{x}dx-\int_{ta}^{tb}\frac{f(0)}{x}dx\right|\\
 & \leq & \int_{ta}^{tb}\left|f(x)-f(0)\right|\cdot\frac{dx}{x}\\
 & \leq & \varepsilon\cdot\frac{1}{\ln(b/a)}\cdot\int_{ta}^{tb}\frac{dx}{x}\\
 & = & \varepsilon.
\end{eqnarray*}
This shows that $\lim_{t\rightarrow0+}\int_{ta}^{tb}\frac{f(x)}{x}dx=f(0)\ln(b/a).$

Comment: How you know that $\delta \in (0,1)$ to $|f(x)-f(0)|< \varepsilon. \frac{1}{\ln(\frac{b}{a})}$?

Comment: It is given that $f$ is a continuous function.

Answer (score 2):

By the substitution $y=\frac x {\epsilon}$ the integral becomes $\int_a^{b} \frac {f(\epsilon x)} x dx$. Can you finish?