# Prove that $\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0^+}\int_{a\varepsilon}^{b\varepsilon}\dfrac{f(x)}{x}\ \text{d}x=f(0)\ln(b/a)$.

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Let $b>a>0$ and $f$ continuous. Prove that $$\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0^+}\int_{a\varepsilon}^{b\varepsilon}\dfrac{f(x)}{x}\ \text{d}x=f(0)\ln(b/a).$$

**My Try**.

Solving the integral by parts. Let $u=f(x)$ and $dv=1/x\ dx$. Then, $du=f'(x)dx$ and $v=\ln x$. So,
$$\begin{align*} \lim_{\varepsilon\to 0^+}\int_{a\varepsilon}^{b\varepsilon}\dfrac{f(x)}{x}\ \text{d}x&=\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0^+}(f(x)\ln x|_{a\varepsilon}^{b\varepsilon}-\int_{a\varepsilon}^{b\varepsilon}f'(x)\ln x\ \text{d}x)\\ &=\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0^+}(f(b\epsilon)ln(b\epsilon)-f(a\epsilon)\ln(a\epsilon))-\lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+}\int_{a\varepsilon}^{b\varepsilon}f'(x)\ln x\ \text{d}x\\
&=f(0)\ln(b/a)-\lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+}\int_{a\varepsilon}^{b\varepsilon}f'(x)\ln x\ \text{d}x.\end{align*}$$

and there in that last part I got stuck. How can I prove that the integral that remains is 0 or remove it from there?

Comment: What are the assumptions on $f$? it seems that you are assuming implicitly that $f$ is differentiable, but you only stated that $f$ is continuous.

Comment: $u=x/\varepsilon$ gives you that $\in^a_b\frac{f(\varepsilon u}{u}\,du$. From this, you can easily show that $\big|\int^b_a \frac{f(\varepsilon u)-f(0)}{u}\,du\Big|\xrightarrow{\varepsilon\rightarrow0}0$

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1470962/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3985689/42969.

Answer (score 3):

The above would be a good way to proceed if you knew that $f'(x)$ exists and is bounded. However if the only information you have on $f$ is its continuity, then there's a better way to proceed. Define the family of intervals $I_{\epsilon}=(a\epsilon, b\epsilon)$. These intervals get smaller and smaller as $\epsilon\to 0$ and eventually collapse onto a single point. By continuity, $f$ attains a maximum and minimum value in $I_\epsilon$ such that

$m_\epsilon\leq f(t)\leq M_\epsilon$

where $\lim_{\epsilon\to 0} m_\epsilon=\lim_{\epsilon\to 0} M_\epsilon=f(0)$ because the interval collapses at that point. Now, we can sandwich the quantity in question as follows

$$m_\epsilon\ln(b/a)\leq\int_{a\epsilon}^{b\epsilon} \frac{f(t)}{t}dt\leq M_{\epsilon}\ln(b/a)$$

from which by sandwiching the limit readily follows.

Answer (score 2):

**hint**

You can't use by parts integration because
You did not say that $ f $ was differentiable.

Let $ \epsilon>0$. with the substitution

$$x=t\epsilon$$

$$\int_{a\epsilon}^{b\epsilon}\frac{f(x)}{x}dx=\int_a^b\frac{f(t\epsilon)}{t}dt$$
$$=f(c\epsilon)\int_a^b\frac{dt}{t}$$
$$=f(c\epsilon)\ln(\frac ba)$$
with $ c\in[a,b] $,
By the second average formula for integrales.

The continuity of $ f $ insures that
$$\lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+}f(c\epsilon)=f(0)$$

Answer (score 0):

MVT for integrals:

$f(t)\displaystyle{\int_{ae}^{be}}(1/x)dx=$

$f(t)(\log (ae)-\log (be))=$

$f(t)\log (a/b)$, where $t \in [ae,be];$

$e \rightarrow 0^+$ implies $t \rightarrow 0^+$.

$\lim_{t \rightarrow 0^+} f(t)=f(0)$, since $f$ is continuous .